# Split Paypal payment into two accounts

Tags: php, paypal, payment-processing

I'm currently creating a system that lets admins create events and allow individuals to register for those events.  Each registration has a fee associated with it, which registrants pay using PayPal.  When an event is created, the admin inputs the PayPal account for which the money will be deposited.  I then charge a set price per registration as the fee for the service.  Is there a way to automatically take my cut of the fee when the payment is submitted to Paypal?

I've looked at the Mass Pay option with PayPal, but that means all the money has to go into a central account and then get divided out from there (if I understand it right).  I would rather stay away from all money going into a central account, as there gets to be a lot of liability involved there.

Now, I'm not 100% tied to PayPal, so if anyone else knows of another service that would work, I would be glad to hear about it.  I'm sure someone else has run into this before...

Comment: this is a nice question. Led me to what I was looking for

Comment: I am looking to do the same put see PayPal has discontinued its adaptive payments. What is the latest way of splitting the payment to two (or more) accounts? I am not fully tied to PayPal either and would appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look into [Paypal Adaptive Payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro). It allows for payments to be sent to two parties.

Comment: and for anyone that comes through later, the method i'm looking at is the Parallel Payments feature of the Adaptive Payments feature.  sample code can be found at https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/sdk and selecting "Adaptive Payments" from the dropdown.