# How to split payments to two accounts using common payment systems?

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment, currency

I'm currently creating a service where people can sell stuff and I as a middle man want to make a cut.

I don't want to accept the whole payment tho and split it later but when a customer is paying to not become a trader.

I know how to make transfers on PayPal and co. but is it possible to split these payments right away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you just use the right keywords for googling you'll find this:

[Split Paypal payment into two accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137891/split-paypal-payment-into-two-accounts)

What I really needed is delayed chained payments which can be found [here.](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro)