# Woocommerce Split payment method for vendors

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, vendor

I'm working on a [Wordpress theme](http://constantin-entertainment.info/shop/) with woocommerce multivendor functionality. Here vendors can upload product from frontend with all necessary details such as product details, payment details etc. What I would like to do is to split the payment for seller(vendor) and store owner(admin). Like if the product is $100, $5 goes to the admin's paypal account. Below I have the Single account payment code. Please help.

```
$paypal_args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_paypal_args', $paypal_args );
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_args' , 'custom_override_paypal_email' );

// Our hooked in function is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_paypal_email( $paypal_args ) {
  $paypal_args['business'] = 'info@ocweb.pro';
  print_r( $paypal_args['business'] );
  return $paypal_args;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split Paypal payment into two accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137891/split-paypal-payment-into-two-accounts)

Comment: Maybe [Product Vendors](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-vendors) would help.